Version Control : Why not use raw uncompressed files for tracking changes?
I have been looking into version control for photo / video data for quite sometime now. My intention is to track changes across sessions, and journaling.
Compressed file formats do not work well with the array of solutions to version control binary data. It probably isn't necessary as the compression algorithm already does the job of identifying patterns that allow for removal of redundant data.
But as I mentioned above, I want to journal the changes I make to my images. Only a VCS of some sort would do this well. From the looks of it, if I work with Raw photo data, I should be able to track the changes using Git VCS. The file sizes will be insane, but I will be able to track accurately, right ?
Just wondering why people don't do this in the industry. I have seen artists maintain raw files. Why not version control the changes ?

Images and code are very different kinds of files so to me it's not surprising that you don't often see version control on images. I can't really see the benefit. If you want to revert one change made early on you would often also have to revert all changes made after that. It would be like having saved the undo history. Crazy amount of data which is unnecessary if you work non-destructively. What kind of changes do you expect to make to your images? Destructive changes or just adding filters and adjustment layers?

have you checked existing solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368407/are-there-revision-control-systems-for-images and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292/version-control-for-graphics

It sounds like you are looking for something like Adobe Lightroom Classic.  Editing is entirely non-destructive, plus you can create virtual copies of RAWs you've already processed, so that you can edit further.

@Wolff I think you are right. Initially I felt that tracking changes (rather than file versions) would be efficient in terms of disk space, but it probably isn't. Most version control systems do allow for storage of file versions. I am destructively editing them, but my guess was that I'll have the original image added to version control, so I can always start with it if things go south.

@Luciano yes i have. Thanks for the tip.

Actually there is a way to keep history of changes when edit image file.
In Photoshop you can set with Edit > Preferences > General in "Edit Log Items" to be on Detailed. And you will have in PSD all the changes you did from the moment of file creation. So you need to store in revision control only the PSD file.
In Lightroom you can set to use side file (XMP) combined with History of edits. And you can store in revision control the instances of XMP which can give you good idea about the changes you did. Be aware some formats (like DNG) do not support (in Lightroom) XMP, they store changes in the DNG file itself.

Yes, I was looking for a cross-application way of tracking changes.

@RutuparnDalvi, each application use own way to keep history and track changes. So I am afraid there is no cross-app solution
